# Possible bottleneck in QGIS 1:n relation?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopackage, relates

I've set up a 1:n relation linking two layers of the same geopackage. That are about 200k polygons in parcels and 700k rows in owners (non spatial). Now it works as expected but it is painstakingly slow to an extend that makes my QGIS project useless: 
Everytime a polygon is clicked on with the identify tool QGIS loads the 700k attributes (window with progress bar). After that clicking on feature form these attributes are being loaded again.

So I'm looking for input on whether there could be a bottleneck and how to get rid of it: The field in parcels as well as its foreign key field in owners have the same name and are the same type (TEXT). Using an exported csv of owners (90 mb) for that relation acts the same way. I don't want to believe that it's the amount of rows causing the lag. Perhaps there is a setting I missed out on? I am using QGIS 3.8.1 on a Ubuntu 18.4.1 machine btw.

Update: When opening the project in QGIS 3.8 on Windows 10 the 700k attributes are only loaded once but the speed is still unacceptable.

Comment: whether or not this *should* work - it might be time to move to a database!!

Comment: srsly? i mean first of all isn't gpkg some kind of DB (yeah i know from that POV a csv is also a DB) and 700k don't seem like a lot, do they? Also the project has to stay somewhat portable and i don't have access to a server.

Comment: its a bit tricky and painful but you can create spatial views in gpkg and QGIS. This may work?

Comment: only 2/3 srsly... I'm sure there are reasons to stay in GPKG, but ideally, joining that much data in that format at the QGIS layer level is not practical... it's gonna cause problems. Spatialite might do the trick, tho...

Comment: "Spatialite might do the trick, tho.." Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think that this post brings up a very important issue.  The Geopackage DB (which uses Spatialite as its underlying engine) has emerged as the next-gen platform for Open-Source spatial data storage and analysis.  It should therefore not be dismissed.  Rather, it should be the focus of QGIS R&D to assure that it is as fast and reliable as possible.